# Angular directive referencing wrong element

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue where a directive i'm using for several similar elements in an ng repeat is showing the wrong element when calling the keyup function.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ARFlsgPdxikpzLScztxU?p=preview

Here's the same code:
**html**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <section ng-controller="MainController" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
      <h3>Item {{$index}}</h3>

      <div class="aliasContainer">
        <input text="text" obj-key="alias" value="{{item.alias}}" ng-keyup="logItem($event, item)">
      </div>

      <div class="nameContainer">
        <input text="text" obj-key="name" value="{{item.name}}" ng-keyup="logItem($event, item)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  console.log("hello ctrl");
  $scope.list = [
    {name: 'Dick Grayson', alias: 'Nightwing'},
    {name: 'Bruce Wayne', alias: 'Batman'},
    {name: 'Jason Todd', alias: 'Robin'}
  ];
}]);
app.directive('objKey', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.logItem = function($event, item) {
       console.log(element);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

The behavior the link function is exhibiting is for each div that is repeated, only the the input in the nameContainer gets passed on keyup (logging the element will show the input in nameContainer of the same parent div even if the input in aliasContainer was the triggering element.)

Comment: You've mixed `ng-repeat` with `ng-controller` in your plunkr. Here is fixed version: http://plnkr.co/edit/ARFlsgPdxikpzLScztxU?p=preview

Comment: thanks. the problem is observable now.

Comment: Please rename this to AngularJS not Angular and i'll remove down vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reuse your directive and keeping its scope separate from outer scope (controller), you need to have a [`isolate scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) to your directive

```
app.directive('objKey', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,     // << Isolating scope
    link: ....
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into directive's scope: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

If you don't isolate the scope, your directive's scope will be the same as the scope when it's declared, in this case it will use the child scope created by ng-repeat.

To fix this, just isolate the scope with `scope: true`